# react native fetchdata using useEffect, but getting the ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getListOfRecipe

Tags: react-native, rest, axios, use-effect

I am trying to fetch data at my react native app using the `useEffect` but I am getting the following error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getListOfRecipe.

I tried to find how to use the `useEffect` but I could not solve it.

**This is my component:**

```
const RecipeCard = ({ }) => {
  const [recipeList, setRecipeList] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    function getListOfRecipe(){
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://192.168.0.7:3333/report',
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: {},
        data: {
          name: "acem"
        }
      })
        .then(function (res) {
          setRecipeList(res)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log("######## CARD CALL - ERROR!!! :: ", error);
        })
        .then(function () {
        });
    } []
  })
    
  console.log('getListOfRecipe: ', getListOfRecipe())
  
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        Recipe Card:
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default RecipeCard
```

Can anyone help me to fix it and make the api fetch call to get the API data?

Comment: What does the extra ```then()``` after the ```catch()``` do? I think you can just remove it also if you want the data you access it from the state not from running the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running a function in a `useEffect()` you need to invoke it, just defining it inside the `useEffect()` will not run it.

Secondly when you want to print the values that you store in state you access them using the 1st element of the `useState` you define. Here you set the data using `setRecipesList` then in order to access it you use `recipeList`.

But the data does not get set immediately as you are fetching the data from an API. So you check whether the data exist then using an `if` statement then you `console.log(recipeList)`.

```
const RecipeCard = ({ }) => {
  const [recipeList, setRecipeList] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    function getListOfRecipe(){
      axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://192.168.0.7:3333/report',
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: {},
        data: {
          name: "acem"
        }
      })
        .then(function (res) {
          setRecipeList(res)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log("######## CARD CALL - ERROR!!! :: ", error);
        })
    getListOfRecipe();   
    } []
  })
    
  if(recipeList){
      console.log(recipeList)
  }

  
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        Recipe Card:
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default RecipeCard
```